# Pandas groupby rolling for future values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, pandas-rolling

I am trying to use a the pandas rolling function with window size 2 with groupby.  This would be pretty standard other than that I also want the window to include the current value **and the proceeding value.**

Specifically, given

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'groups':['a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b'], 
                   'info': [i for i in range(10)]})
```

I want

```
pd.DataFrame({'groups':['a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b'], 
                   'info': [i for i in range(10)],
                   'groupsum':[1, 3, 5, 7, nan,  11, 13, 15, 17, nan]})
```

I have tried 2 strategies, both of which did not work.  I first tried

```
indexer = pd.api.indexers.FixedForwardWindowIndexer(window_size=2)
df['groupsum'] = df.groupby('groups')['info'].rolling(window=indexer).mean().values
```

This way leads to kernel crashing, even for this toy dataframe.  Very curious as to why.
My second way is to reverse the dataframe then use a regular groupby rolling operation:

```
df = df.iloc[::-1].copy()
df.index = range(df.shape[0])
df['groupsum'] = df.groupby('groups')['info'].rolling(2).sum().values
```

While the kernel does not crash with this method, it does not yield the dataframe I'd hoped for; it yields

```
pd.DataFrame({'groups':['a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b'], 
                   'info': [i for i in range(10)],
                   'groupsum':[nan,  7.,  5.,  3.,  1., nan, 17., 15., 13., 11.]})
```

I suppose there is an obvious solution here that I just don't know.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If assign numpy array instead Series it not aligned correctly, never do it for avoid this problems. Need remove first level of `MultiIndex` by [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) with `drop=True` and then change order by indexing:

```
indexer = pd.api.indexers.FixedForwardWindowIndexer(window_size=2)
df['groupsum'] = df.groupby('groups')['info'].rolling(window=indexer).sum().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
print (df)
  groups  info  groupsum
0      a     0       1.0
1      a     1       3.0
2      a     2       5.0
3      a     3       7.0
4      a     4       NaN
5      b     5      11.0
6      b     6      13.0
7      b     7      15.0
8      b     8      17.0
9      b     9       NaN
```

---

```
df = df.iloc[::-1].copy()
df.index = range(df.shape[0])
df['groupsum'] = df.groupby('groups')['info'].rolling(2).sum().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
df = df.iloc[::-1]
print (df)
  groups  info  groupsum
9      a     0       1.0
8      a     1       3.0
7      a     2       5.0
6      a     3       7.0
5      a     4       NaN
4      b     5      11.0
3      b     6      13.0
2      b     7      15.0
1      b     8      17.0
0      b     9       NaN
```

Comment: If your groups are not alphabetized, you can get the correct results in the first block by simply changing `df.groupby('groups')`  to `df.groupby('groups', sort = False)`.  Thanks again for the help @jezrael.

Answer (score 1):

Another method:

```
df["groupsum"] = df.groupby("groups")["info"].apply(lambda x: x + x.shift(-1))
```

```
>>> df
  groups  info  groupsum
0      a     0       1.0
1      a     1       3.0
2      a     2       5.0
3      a     3       7.0
4      a     4       NaN
5      b     5      11.0
6      b     6      13.0
7      b     7      15.0
8      b     8      17.0
9      b     9       NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    return dd[::-1].rolling(2).sum()

df.assign(groupsum=df.groupby('groups').apply(function1).droplevel(0))

 groups  info  groupsum
0      a     0       1.0
1      a     1       3.0
2      a     2       5.0
3      a     3       7.0
4      a     4       NaN
5      b     5      11.0
6      b     6      13.0
7      b     7      15.0
8      b     8      17.0
9      b     9       NaN
```